# Does nodejS express server gets up and running without having to write app.listen() statement?

Tags: node.js, express

I have removed the app.listen reference from app.js file in my nodeJS express appilcation.

Even after removing it my application's undeclared server, is reachable on port localhost:3000.

Does express module start and maintain a server on port 3000 if the application code does not explicitly declare one?

Thanks.

Comment: No. it does not start automaticly

Comment: I have an app in which there is no app.listen. It is receiving API when sent on port 3000. Moreover, when I move this app to cloud via cloud foundry, even there it works. The final app URL is receiving calls(in this case port does not have to be mentioned).

Comment: Post your package.json and some example code. perhapse you are using a module that produce this strange behavior. There is no possible way that your app listen on port xxx if you dont explicit create a network socket. A bit more information would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, another instance of that server might have been instantiated from another command-line.
Use, "ps -ef | grep node" and then "kill -9 " to identify and kill the already-instantiated process. This should help sort/fix your issue.

Recommend using nodemon to avoid these issues. Nodemon automatically restarts the server whenever a code-change is observed.
Sample here: `nodemon -e js,hbs,handlebars,css,png,jpg,jpeg,svg,env src/app.js`

The above meant, start node with src/app.js and keep an eye on any of the jS, HBS, handlebars and etc content. And whenever there is a change in any of those files, restart the src/app.js

Comment: No there's no other instance. Checked this multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the answer is YES.

Without a listen statement anywhere in the project, my app is receiving API GET and POST calls on port 3000 when run locally. Same behaviour when run on cloud(however cloud URL does not need a port number).

Quite Strange but it does work.

However, Is this advisable for production applications?